# Behaviour of casting random to a string

Tags: string, random, casting, arduino

It seems i cannot cast the returned long of random, what happens here exactly?

This generates a random number every time I restart my arduino program.

```
randomSeed(analogRead(1)); 
int randomSerial = random(1000,9999);
serialRan = String(randomSerial);
```

This outputs the same random number every time I restart my arduino program.

```
randomSeed(analogRead(1));
serialRan = String(random(1000,9999));
```

Comment: Try changing `randomSeed(analogRead(1));` to `randomSeed(analogRead(A0));`. If this helps, I'll explain it in detail by posting an answer.

Comment: No, same result.

Comment: I tried your code on my Uno. Both versions produce equally random numbers. Or rather, equally _unrandom_ (with frequent repetitions), as a floating analog input is a notoriously poor source of entropy. For a better seeding of the PRNG, see [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/22081/7508) and [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/50742/7508).